# How to set the attributes to a generic @Service class in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, design-patterns

I'm new to Spring Boot, so bare me with my basic question here.

I want to build a generic `@Service` class that has well defined methods that don't even need to be overwritten.

The only thing this class needs is to adjust its attributes based on which `Controller` method was called. Basically, this class works as a Job handler that needs to adjust some parameters so its methods can perform what they're supposed to compute. The job will always have the same workflow, calling the methods in the same order, but it will obtain different results depending on the parameters/attributes it receives, which, as I said before, are defined by the controller methods.

The only attribute it has beside the ones that adjust the job's workflow is an autowired `@Repository` object that will save the results of the job in a database.

Maybe I could simply instantiate an Job Handler object and call a constructor with the paramaters I need for the job, but I don't know what is the "Spring way" of doing this, considering how Spring works with dependency injection and I need a `@Repository` object embbeded into the Job Handler service.

I would really appreciate if anyone could write a sample code/example so I could understand how this can be done with Spring Boot so I don't have to duplicate code or Service Classes.

Comment: *"Maybe I could simply instantiate an Job Handler"* it's definitely not the Spring way, and you shouldn't do that. Could you add a code snippet to make it more clear?

Comment: You could make this a better question for SO (and also help yourself) by taking a shot at implementing dependency injection with Spring. Do some googling, write some code, and if you get stuck while coding, post it here so we can see exactly where you're at. Take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). "Please write an example" is not a great question for SO, because there is no right or wrong answer.

Answer (score 0):

The Spring way for this case would be to create a Bean of your JobHandler, where you inject the necessary dependencies, like your Repository:

```
@Configuration
class MyConfiguration {

    @Bean
    MyJobHandler myJobHandler(MyRepository myRepository) {
        return new MyJobHandler (myrepository);
    }

}
```

Alternatively, if you do not want a configuration class, you could declare your JobHandler as a Component and inject the repository in the constructor:

```
@Component
class MyJobHandler {

    private MyRepository myRepository;

    public MyJobHandler myJobHandler(MyRepository myRepository) {
        this.myRepository = myRepository;
    }

}
```

Comment: The Spring way somewhat more traditionally would be to autowire the dependency with `@Autowired`. Either as a private field or as constructor parameter of your Service.

Comment: Yes, exactly. The repository dependency here is implicitly autowired!

Comment: That is not what I meant. The typical spring way would be to have the beans be picked up automatically by component scanning relying entirely on `@Autowired`, doing away with the need for explicitly instantiating it through configuration yourself.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. I added an example to my answer.